# Is there a way to filter the results of a function call in R?

Tags: r

I have a general question and a specific example.  The general question is:  Is there a way to capture the results of a function so I can filter on them without creating a temporary variable?

This is the exmaple.  If I want to find the highest correlation in a correlation matrix that is not 1.0, I can:

```
tmp <- cor(stocks)
max(tmp[tmp < 1.0])
```

Is there a way to do this in one line of code?

Note: I know I could probably get the same result by setting the diagonals to 0 in this particular instance, but I would like to understand the more general case.  How can I subset or filter the result of cor(stocks)?

Comment: `with(list(tmp=cor(stocks)),max(tmp[tmp < 3]))` ?

Comment: Yeah.  With would seem to be what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: However, there's no harm in creating a temporary variable, because R is doing it under the hood anyway...

Comment: Right.  but then I have to dispose of it manually.  If R does it under the hood, it doesn't pollute my namespace.

Comment: Yes, that's true... I just pointed out that because one can think that R could perform the operation in an optimized way without allocating anything new, but it's not...

Comment: If you make this an actual answer, I'd be happy to choose it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`with`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/with.html) function :

```
with(list(tmp=cor(stocks)),max(tmp[tmp < 3]))
```

Please note that this is not more efficient than your approach, since you're still creating a temporary variable under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using the pipe operator from `magrittr`:

```
library('magrittr')
data("EuStockMarkets")
ans <-
  cor(EuStockMarkets) %>%
  .[. < 1] %>%
  max
```

gives `0.9911539`.

The pipe `%>%` takes the results of the calculation before it and passes it to the next line, where you can refer to it using the placeholder `.`. The final line is a short way of writing `max(.)`.